# In iOS Swift, After app is sent to background and taken back, response is not coming if the request is kept open for 30 seconds

Tags: ios, swift, networking, background

In Swift, I am using the `urlsession` framework for fetching data from APIs. I am adding requests into `operationqueue` and internally I am doing an operation to make sure the fire in FIFO format. I sent a request and the backend will only respond after 30 seconds of receiving the request. Its all working fine if app is not minimised.

If I sent a request, then suddenly send the app into background (not close) and after 8-10 seconds if I take the app to foreground, then I am receiving the response.

Since my app is not supporting any background modes, is this behaviour because the requests are somehow dying when I sent the app to background?

Comment: Likely so. You only get a couple seconds to do work once you enter the background, unless you request more. If you need it delivered immediately, even in the background, you can either request an extension to your background time before you make the request (even if you're in the foreground) or use a `URLSession` configured to allow background processing

Comment: @MichaelHulet How can I request for an extension to the background time?
Is it using BGProcessingTaskRequest?

Comment: No. Use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`

Answer (score 0):

Please check if **Background Fetch** is checked in **Signing and Capabilities**

[image]